# React Native flatlist: why is onViewableItemsChanged called at initial render?

Tags: react-native

I have a simple question: why is onViewableItemsChanged called at initial render without a **horizontal** flatlist being even visible? This flatlist is only shown when scrolling to it.

How can I fix this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It is also possible for onViewableItemsChanged to be called during the initial render of a FlatList, even if the list is not yet visible on the screen. This can happen if the initialNumToRender prop of the FlatList is set to a value greater than 0, causing the FlatList to render more items than the ones that are currently visible on the screen.

In such cases, the onViewableItemsChanged callback will receive the list of viewable items that have been rendered, but they will not yet be visible to the user. This is the expected behavior of the FlatList component, and it is designed to optimize the performance of the list by pre-rendering items that are likely to become visible in the near future.

If you want to avoid having onViewableItemsChanged being called during the initial render, you can set the initialNumToRender prop to 0, or use other techniques to control the visibility of the FlatList component, such as conditional rendering based on a state variable or a prop passed from the parent component.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Why is it the expected behavior? I mean this e.g does not happen in case of a vertical flatlist… what could be here the explanation? From the prop I would expect it to only call the onViewableItemsChanged function when visibility changes what is not the case when the flatlist is not even visible… :)